# Laravel lazy eager loading with repository

Tags: php, laravel, repository, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I started working with repositories in Laravel and came across a situation where I'm not sure if I'm handeling this the right way...

User repository:

```
interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function findByID(int $user_id);
    public function load(User $user, array $relations);
}

class UserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function findByID(int $user_id)
    {
        return User::find($user_id);
    }
    public function load(User $user, array $relations)
    {
        $user->load($relations);
    }
}
```

Client basecontroller:

```
protected $user_repository, $client;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(Request $request, UserRepositoryInterface $user_repository)
    {
        $this->user_repository = $user_repository;
        $this->client = $this->user_repository->findByID($request->route('client_id'));
    }
}
```

Some extension of the client basecontroller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\...\Controller as ClientsController;

class SomeController extends ClientsController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->user_repository->load($this->client, ['addresses', 'bank_accounts', 'etc']);
        return $this->client;
    }
}
```

While the index() functions does show the client with related models, it feels like my approach is wrong, but sinds I already have the client it feels more natural to load the missing related models then to do the call below (where I fetch the user again):

```
$this->client = $this->user_repository->findByIDWithRelations($user_id, ['...']);
```

Because the load() function in the repository doesn't return anything and I assign nothing in the index() function it feels bogus somehow... Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Update:

Take for example this piece of code below (does not work):

```
function addToArray($array, $value)
{
    array_push($array, $value);
}

$array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

addToArray($array, 'd');

foreach($array as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

The way I approached this in Laravel feels very similar, which makes me feel it's wrong :-).

Answer (score 0):

While this topic may have different opinions, there's already some opinionated open-source packages that provides a simple but intuitive implementation of repositories for Laravel that allows you to use the following syntax for example:

```
$repository->with(['relationship']);
```

So that your repository is clean, all relations are lazy loaded unless you call the `with` method and pass an array to eager load some relations. The API of the following package is pretty simple & intuitive and I think it's going to help you in your approach.

Checkout: https://github.com/rinvex/repository/